# MediaPipe Holistic with Flutter for mobile app development

Tags: android, flutter, api, machine-learning, mediapipe

I am looking for ways to use [MediaPipe Holistic](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/holistic.html) within the Flutter to develop mobile apps. I know that MediaPipe provide solution API's for:

- Python
- Javascript

I have also seen that several MediaPipe solutions/models are made available through [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/) including:

- Face detection
- Pose detection
- Face Mesh detection
- .... and more

These models are in fact provided by the [Flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit), however the list does not include the Holistic model yet.

I want to build a mobile (Android) app where video images are processed in real time by the model. My question is if anyone has suggestions on how to implement this in flutter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript within flutter with webview or flutter_js. i did not try webview plugin but I think it is what you are looking for.

[Webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example)

[flutter_js](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).